# ActionBarDrawerToggle without support-v4 library?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am creating android appilcation for API level 15+. So I don't want support-v4 library in my dependencies.

What I am trying to do is to implement basic App drawer (navigation drawer) functionality.

Every tutorial I have found (including one on Google's official android site) suggested usage of ActionBarDrawerToggle to control opening and hiding of drawer. But this class resides in android support-v4 library, and I have found no similar classes in standard indroid API 15+ platform (not even in android API 19 platform). So my question is - how do I properly create app drawer for minimum API level 15 without creating unnecessary dependencies on support libraries?

Comment: Are you implementing your own Drawer? Are you just asking how to get the Home Button to work without the ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: It would be enough for me to achieve the same result as in http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html WITHOUT using compatibility libraries.

Comment: Then I think this question is too broad. Since DrawerLayout is part of the support package, it would have to be re-implemented, as well. Your title specifies the toggle, so is that the only way you want to open/close the Drawer? Or do you want to be able to drag it opened/closed, too? Are components that are deprecated, but still usable, acceptable? Is this for a specific use case, or does it need to be generic as possible? Considering your comment, this question is asking for replacements for several non-trivial components of the support package.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. The question is incorrect and difficult to answer, so I will close it. It seems strange to me that a "reference" nav drawer implementation is not available even in recent API levels, though. What's the point of all this "minSdkVersion=15" propaganda if I still must use compatibility with api level 4.